# I'm working on sending data from my primary Discord account's channel to my secondary Discord account's channel using webhooks

Tags: discord, xmlhttprequest, fetch, bots

Hi so i'm working on a project involving sending data from my primary Discord account's channel to my secondary Discord account's channel using webhooks within the Discord webpage itself. However, my attempts to achieve this by utilizing the fetch and post methods have been unsuccessful, consistently resulting in a frustrating error 400. Despite careful implementation, I'm unsure why I'm encountering this issue. Can you provide insights or guidance on what might be causing the error and how I can effectively resolve it? My intention is to securely transmit data stored in my website's local storage to the designated channel in my secondary Discord account. Any assistance in overcoming this roadblock would be greatly appreciated.

I tried changing the request type to xhr but its the same result. I hopefully expect an answer to the issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Found out they have a thing called connect-src policy that prevents developers from sending data on discord webpage if the endpoint isnt part of their domain. For example, the connect-src policy isn't allowing me to send data through my discord  webhooks. Please does anyone have a solution to it?